# Sort ObservableCollection with data from Firebase - Xamarin Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xaml, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I display my data from a Firebase database to a Xamarin app.

My data on the database is structured like this:[image]

And my code to call that data is the following:

display.xaml.cs:

```
    private void tableLoad()
{
    var collection = firebaseClient
        .Child("Example")
        .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
        .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        {
            if (dbevent != null)
            {
                DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
            }
        });
}
```

display.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

myDatabaseRecord.cs:

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }    
}
```

What can I change to my "Display.xaml.cs" to sort the data I retrieve from firebase? I tried adding something like this:

```
private void tableLoad()
    {
        var collection = firebaseClient
            .Child("Example")
            .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
            .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
            {
                if (dbevent != null)
                {
                    DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
                }
            });
    DatabaseItems = new ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>(DatabaseItems.OrderBy(i => i.Date));
    }
```

But when I run the app it doesn't return any item from the database

Comment: first, if you want to sort by date you should really store the date as a DateTime,not a string.  Second, your is probably working, but you are reassigning the value of `DatabaseItems` without raising a `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason commented, the way you currently store the data doesn't make it easy to sort on. If you want to store the date as a string, store it in ISO 8859-1 format, which *does* allow sorting:

```
"2022-04-05"
```

Once you use this format for your `Date` properties, you can use Firebase's built-in ordering operator to get the child nodes in date order:

```
firebaseClient
    .Child("Example")
    .OrderByChild("Date")
    .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
    .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        ...
```

Comment: Even if I try order it by Name, instead of date due to the wrong format, it returns an error: "ChildQuery does not contain a definition for OrderByChild  and no accessible extension method OrderByChild accepting a first argument of type ChildQuery could be found"

Comment: Ah, it might be called `OrderBy("Date")` on Xamarin I see.

Comment: But even if I use the `OrderBy("Name")` It won't order anything on the display

Comment: Did you already run the code in a debugger? I'd specifically check on ` if (dbevent != null)`, as I'm not sure how the list of data you observe would get translates into a single `MyDatabaseRecord` object.